# Use fontawesome icons and remove icon-spinner icon-spin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have a problem with fontawesome I can't remove an appended icon once it has `icon-spin` class

```
<h1>This is the title</h1>

<script>
  function updateByAjax() {
    $h1 = $('h1').append('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>')
    $.get('/url', function(resp) { 
      $h1.html(resp.title).find('.icon-spinner').remove()
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to wrap around the spinner in another tag

```
<h1>This is the title</h1>

<script>
  function updateByAjax() {
    $h1 = $('h1').append('<span class='ajax-wait'><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i></span>')
    $.get('/url', function() { 
      $h1.html(resp.html).find('.ajax-wait').text('').remove() 
    })
  }
</script>
```